# How do I replace "Username" in the Wordpress login form?

Tags: login, wp-login-form

[image]

I would like to replace "Username" in the Wordpress login form with another word.  How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gettext` filter:

```
/**
 * Rename the 'Username' label in wp-login.php
 *  
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159507/26350
 */

add_filter( 'wp_login_errors',
    function( $errors )
    {
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_change_username', 99, 3 );
        return $errors;
    }
);

function wpse_change_username( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    $old = "Username";
    $new = "Jediname";

    if ( $untranslated_text === $old )
        $translated_text = $new;

    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    return $translated_text;
}
```

where we hook into the `wp_login_errors`, which is very close to the `username` input.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Username->Jediname]